# Find the value of $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{a-1}\,\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^{2}},\,$ where $\,0<a<2$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus, analyticity

Using the [Residue Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) calculate
$$
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{a-1}\,\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^{2}},\,\,\,\, \text{where}\,\,\,0<a<2.
$$
My solution comes out to be
$$ \frac{\pi}{2}[i^{a-1}-(-i)^{a-1}]$$

How to proceed from here since the solution of a rational expression must be independent of  $i$

Comment: Why don't you compute $i^{a-1}$ and $(-i)^{a-1}$?

Comment: Write $i^{a-1}=e^{(a-1)\ln(i)}=e^{(a-1)\pi i/2}=\cos((a-1)\pi/2)+i\sin((a-1)\pi/2)$. Do the same with $(-i)^{a-1}$. Likely the $i$'s simplify.

Comment: $$ i^{a−1}=e^{(a−1)ln(i)}$$ how did this come to be? i'm sorry but i don't understand this

Comment: @Irrational_Number Waht does $x^a$ mean to you?

Comment: $a$ is some constant lying between 0 and 2

Comment: It is the property of logarithm of being the inverse of the exponential. $e^{\ln(x)}=x$. Put $x=i^{a-1}$. You get $i^{a-1}=e^{\ln(i^{a-1})}$. Then use that $\ln(A^B)=B\ln(A)$.

Comment: whoops needed a correction in the answer

Comment: using this method i'll just get the form of $e^{ix}-e^{-ix}$ which would be $2isinx$, the $i$ would still persist

Comment: But at least one $i$ remains outside of the exponentials:$i^{a-1}=-i*e^{i \pi /2 *a}$

Comment: No `\displaystyle` in titles please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I imagine you have integrated $\,\,f(z)=\dfrac{z^{a-1}}{z^2+1},\,$ along the contour 
$\,\gamma=\gamma_1\cup\gamma_2\cup\gamma_3\cup\gamma_4,\,$ where
$$
\gamma_1=[-R,-\varepsilon],\quad\gamma_2=\{\varepsilon\mathrm{e}^{i(\pi-t)}: t\in[0,\pi]\},\quad \gamma_3=[\varepsilon,R],\quad\gamma_4=\{R\mathrm{e}^{it}: t\in[0,\pi]\}.
$$ 
In such case
$$
z^{a-1}=\mathrm{e}^{(a-1)\log z},
$$
where $\log z$ is a branch of logarithm defined in 
$$
\Omega=\mathrm{C}\setminus \{it: t\in (-\infty,0]\},
$$ 
as follows. If $z=r\mathrm{e}^{i\vartheta}$, then $\log z=\log r+i\vartheta$, with $$
\vartheta\in (-\pi/2,3\pi,2).
$$
So, in such case, Residue Theorem provides 
$$
\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz=2\pi i\,\mathrm{Res}\left(\frac{z^{a-1}}{1+z^2},i\right)=2\pi i\cdot\frac{i^{a-1}}{2i}=\pi\mathrm{e}^{i(a-1)\pi/2}=-i\pi \mathrm{e}^{ia\pi/2}.
$$ 
Clearly
$$
\lim_{R\to\infty,\,\varepsilon\to 0}\int_{\gamma_1}f(z)\,dz=
\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{z^{a-1}}{z^2+1}=(-1)^{a-1}\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{a-1}\,dx}{1+x^2}=-\mathrm{e}^{ia\pi}\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{a-1}\,dx}{1+x^2},
$$
since $(-1)^{a-1}=\mathrm{e}^{i(a-1)\pi}=-\mathrm{e}^{ia\pi},\,$ and
$$
\lim_{R\to\infty,\,\varepsilon\to 0}\int_{\gamma_3}f(z)\,dz=
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{z^{a-1}}{z^2+1}=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{a-1}\,dx}{1+x^2}.
$$
Meanwhile,
$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\int_{\gamma_2}f(z)\,dz=0$ and 
$\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{\gamma_4}f(z)\,dz=0$. Hence, altogether
$$
(1-\mathrm{e}^{ia\pi})\int_{0}^\infty\frac{x^{a-1}\,dx}{1+x^2}=
\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0,\,\,R\to\infty}\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz=
2\pi i\,\mathrm{Res}\left(\frac{z^{a-1}}{1+z^2},i\right)
=-i\pi \mathrm{e}^{ia\pi/2}.
$$
Hence
$$
\int_{0}^\infty\frac{x^{a-1}\,dx}{1+x^2}=\frac{i\pi \mathrm{e}^{ia\pi/2}}{\mathrm{e}^{ia\pi}-1}=\frac{i\pi }{\mathrm{e}^{ia\pi/2}-\mathrm{e}^{-ia\pi/2}}=\frac{\pi}{2\sin (a\pi/2)}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/176216), it is shown that for $m\gt0$ and $-1<n<m-1$
$$
\frac{\pi}{m}\csc\left(\pi\frac{n+1}{m}\right)=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{1+x^m}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
Plug in $n=a-1$ and $m=2$ to get that for $0\lt a\lt2$
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{a-1}}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac\pi2\csc\left(\frac{\pi a}2\right)
$$

Comment: Is the downvote because I cited another residue theorem/contour integration answer? If so, I believe it is better simply to cite a previous answer than to replicate it everywhere it applies.

Comment: +1. I agree with you. We don't have to "reinvent the wheel".